# CSS fake table divs, expand inside div to fill the 100% of total width

Tags: html, css

im trying to use a "fake" table using divs.

The structure of the fake table is simple

```
<div id="fatable">
   <div id="fatable1"></div>
   <div id="fatable2"></div>
   <div id="fatable3"></div>
   <div id="fatable4"></div>
   <div id="fatable5"></div>
   <div id="fatable6"></div>
   <div id="fatable7"></div>
   <div id="fatable8"></div>
</div>

#fatable {
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#fatable1, #fatable2, #fatable3, #fatable4, #fatable5, #fatable6, #fatable7, #fatable8 {
    float:left;
}
```

My problem now is that the element called #fatable3 must expand it self so #fatable always reach the 100% of the possible with..

`#fatable3` is a search input field that will be "elastic" so each time the with is 1900px insted of 1200 just for example this element must "grow" to #fatable reach the 100%..

i even have  a jsfiddle, cause i remember this wasent so hard. but if set 100% width for `#fatable3` then this elements take the 100% width of the page making `#fatable` like 175% really of the screen width.

http://jsfiddle.net/DDMMc/

Or do i have to move to a real table to achieve this?

Here is the simplified version of the jsfiddle, i need all to be just one Row, but when i set the 100% width for a inline element, it drops , cause it takes the 100% of the width not of the space left inside.. hope you can understand me

Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/sU5Kx/

Comment: That jsFiddle is way more complicated than your code here, perhaps you could simplify it a bit?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TabethaMoe I'm wondering the same thing.  OP, if you need a table, then why not simply use a table?

Comment: Im really about to chage to a table.. because its a pain to change all html .. but i will here is the simple jsfiddle, look the element 3 (#fatable3) is getting the 100% width of the page, http://jsfiddle.net/sU5Kx/

Comment: @JulesMartinez, look into making `#fatable` position: relative.  It will redefine the context of all the elements within, so width: 100% won't mean the width of the screen, but the width of `#fatable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use the css code for div table layout. It is pretty clean.
I updated your fiddle here 
[a link](http://jsfiddle.net/sU5Kx/8/)

Serach for further information **css div tablelayout**.

```
#fatable {
max-width:100%;
width:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
display: table;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a guess and hope this is what you want..

Here is the fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DDMMc/1/)**

Jus add this  to your fatable3..

```
 #fatable #fatable3
{
   float:left;
   width:100% !important;
}
```

this will change ua design but u can adjust other divs as u want...